# Identifying Cells by Strikethrough in Google Sheets

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, strikethrough

I'm trying to calculate something (((cells with strikethrough)/(total cells in the column))*100) on a google sheet and am new to Google Script Editor.
Script 1:

```
function countStrike(range) {
var count = 0;
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
        .getRange(range)
        .getFontLines()
    .reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a.concat(b);
    })
    .forEach(function (el) {
        if (el === "line-through") {
            count++
        }
    });
return count;}
```

Script 1 Error:

> "Range not found. (line 9)"

Script 2:

```
function countStrike(B2:B50) {
var count = 0;
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
        .getRange()
        .getFontLines()
    .reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a.concat(b);
    })
    .forEach(function (el) {
        if (el === "line-through") {
            count++
        }
    });
return count;
}
```

Script 2 Error:

> "Missing formal parameter. (line 1)"

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? Where is the line 9 in your script? And how do you call ``countStrike(range)``? ``SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range).getFontLines()`` is correct. So I thought that there might be an error for ``range`` when you call ``countStrike(range)``.

Comment: Line 9 is the ".forEach(function (el) {" line. I'm not sure how I should define it because my aim was to be able to define the range in the function, like how SUM(B5:B20) works

Comment: You want to use as a custom function like ``=countStrike("B5：B20")``. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: But I don't want to have to change the range in the code every time. I want to be able to do it from the spreadsheet, custom.

Comment: You want to use the script as a custom function. If my understanding is correct, how about this? At first, it supposes that the script is the container-bound script. Under this condition, when ``=countStrike("B5:B20")`` is put to a cell, the same error occurs?

Comment: Now, a different error occurs, "Missing formal parameter.(line 1)". I also changed line 4 to .getRange()

Comment: Can you update your question by including your latest script?

Comment: Added the latest script

Comment: Thank you for updating it. But I'm sorry. I'm not sure what you want to do.

Comment: I want it to be able to count the number of cells in a column with the strikethrough applied

Comment: From your comment, I had thought that you want to use the function as a custom function. But now, it seems that you want to change it. I cannot understand the direction you want. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: You want to retrieve the number of cells of "line-through". I can understanding about it. For this, I think that your script works. How do you want to use the function? About this, I cannot still understand.

Comment: Thank you for being really patient with me! The script currently isn't working because it gives a new issue with the first line. My aim is to be able to use it like a Microsoft excel function, like SUM(B2:B50), where just writing that will add all the cell values from B2,B3,B4 to B50. In this case, it would ignore cells that do not have a line-through and give back the number of cells that do in the custom input. Maybe I want cells C5:C30, something like that, if that helps.

Comment: @I'-'I But now that I have the quotes, it gives me this Missing Formal Parameter edit, that I don't know how to solve.

Comment: @JoeDoe I think that when ``function countStrike(B2:B50) {`` is put in the script, the script cannot be saved. So I think that you are better to use the first script as I'-'I says.

Comment: I got kind of confused by your recent comments, so I edited my question for clarification. Can you please tell me what you mean now with regards to the script? Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm just running it from the Script Editor, I haven't been able to get it into the spreadsheet yet. And that too, it won't run successfully

Comment: @JoeDoe When you run ``countStrike(range)`` with the script editor, the error occurs. Because ``range`` is not given. So when you want to run it, for example, please put a function of ``function run() {Logger.log(countStrike("B2:B50"))}`` to the script editor, and run ``run()``.

Comment: Nice! Now it works in the script editor, but is there a way to control this from the spreadsheet itself?

Comment: @JoeDoe when called as a custom function, where you select the range as cells (e.g. `A1: =foo(B2:B50)`), the function receives a 2d `Array` (an `Array` of `Array`s of values) from the input cells. If the cells are given as a string, e.g. `A1: =foo("B2:B50")`, then you can use the `getRange` method to get a `Range` using the function's input. Note that custom functions will not recalculate constantly - they require changed input parameters to recalculate. Changing formatting will not trigger this state change.